# Error amplification in linear regression with uncertainties in design matrix

Tags: least-squares, uncertainty, errors-in-variables

I am running a least squares regression, and I am trying to estimate the uncertainty on the fit solution. The problem is, I have an uncertainty in my design matrix coefficients as well as in my predictors. So given $||Ax - b||_2$ being minimized, and uncertainties $\sigma_b$ and $\sigma_A$ on the coefficients of $b$ and $A$, what is the uncertainty $\sigma_x$ on the resulting vector $x$?

Comment: If you have errors in your design variables, ordinary least squares is not very good. The usual LS estimators are actually biased in this setting. A good way out is to use a [errors-in-variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models) model, in which case you also should get the answer to your question for free.

Comment: that looks great, I will try it. Thanks, I am not sure how to upvote your answer here?